# How can I set the visibility of a button from a custom surfaceview?

Tags: android, button

So basically I'm making a really simple game on android. Within my `Activity` I have a `SurfaceView` and some `Buttons` labelled **play** and **restart**. I set the visibility of the `Buttons` accordingly so that when the game is in the menu state it sets the play button to VISIBLE and in the game state it's set to GONE. The restart button is set to GONE throughout until the player loses the game. My problem is, when game is in it's lose state, how can the `SurfaceView` access the **restart** button from the main `Activity` to set it to VISIBLE? Is this how it's supposed to work, or is there another way? I'm kinda new to android, but I think this is pretty important so the user can really navigate through the app, especially in games. Maybe there's some beginner stuff I have to go back to?

Comment: How to accept an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your class structure, set a member variable to hold the reference to your button, or, if you are holding a context or the main layout, use Activity.findViewById(ButtonID) or a parent views View.findViewByID(ButtonID). Or you can introduce a new e.g. OnGameState interface whose implementations get notified when the game state changes. One of those implementations would then set the button's state.

Answer (score 0):

write a new restart button programmatically, add it to your "lost/game-over" activity's layout . Write the appropriate code for its `onClick()`(something like finish() the present activity and launch the "new-game" activity) .